# Developer License for windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8.1, licensing

After `Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration` in powershell, I get the following alert:

[image]

```
Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration : Exception from HRESULT: 0x8024401B
At line:1 char:1
+ Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AcquireDeveloperLicenseException,Microsoft.Windows.DeveloperLicense.Commands.ShowWindows
   DeveloperLicenseRegistrationCommand
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit, Windows is activated.`Windows8.1-KB2913270-x64` is already installed on my pc.Proxy is properly set which I have verified using `netsh winhttp show proxy`.

P.S> This isn't a duplicate question. None of the solutions to similar problems has worked for me.

Comment: 0x8024401B = WU_E_PT_HTTP_STATUS_PROXY_AUTH_REQ = Same as HTTP status 407 - proxy authentication is required. you have proxy issues.

Comment: Thanks for hint! But am not able to figure out how to set the proxy. Is it something to do with registry settings? `netsh winhttp show proxy` displays:
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Proxy Server(s) :  202.141.80.19:3128
    Bypass List     :  (none)

Comment: Ask your IT support for help about proxy configuration

Comment: have you fixed your proxy settings?

Comment: There is some issue for internet access for windows machines from the lab I am working. When I did it from my room, the 0x8024401B was no more present but 0x800f0200 now. Tried installing some registry cleaner. I am now trying to find solution to proxy reset to 127.0.0.1 again and again in Windows 8.1. No working solution found yet.

Comment: 0x800f0200 =  SPAPI_E_NO_ASSOCIATED_CLASS - The INF or the device information set or element does not have an associated install class. are you sure this is the correct code? this means a .inf file for driver setup has issues

Comment: I am not sure `0x800f0200` was the code. I will be able to reproduce the error after I come up with a working solution for `proxy reset to 127.0.0.1 again and again in Windows 8.1`.

Comment: ask on superuser.com http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8.1 how to prevent the proxy reset

Comment: Thanks .. got help here http://superuser.com/questions/1182881/proxy-reset-to-loopback-address-in-windows-8-1?noredirect=1#comment1713232_1182881 . Now trying to solve `0x80072f00` = `WININET_E_FORCE_RETRY`.

Comment: `0x80072f00` was solved with the help from here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4155f8ee-636a-4293-9cba-0694e8f0bcfd/we-couldnt-get-your-developer-license-for-windows-81-preview-error-0x80072f00?forum=toolsforwinapps. I have a developer license now. Thanks @magicadre1981 for the help throughout.

Comment: ok, post in your own answer what you did to solve it. later you can mark your reply as answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @magicandre1981 to help me solve the error.

Short answer: Use open internet to avoid/solve any internet access related issues while getting developer license for windows 8.1.

Long answer:

If behind any proxy verify if the proxy is set properly using `netsh winhttp show proxy`.

I got error `0x8024401B` while trying to get developers license for windows 8.1. This error occurred because there was some issue for internet access for windows machines from the lab I was working. This issue was solved after I accessed internet from outside the lab.

Further there was `0x80072f00` error. I was still behind a proxy server. After reading from here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4155f8ee-636a-4293-9cba-0694e8f0bcfd/we-couldnt-get-your-developer-license-for-windows-81-preview-error-0x80072f00?forum=toolsforwinapps, I used open internet to get developer license which solved the error.